# Reading information from a ListView from another thread in Visual Basic

Tags: .net, multithreading, listview, invoke, basic

I am having a problem reading an item from a ListView. The ListView is in the main thread, and the part where I read it out is in another class and another thread. My code is as follows:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim ltm As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem
        ltm.Text = "test1"
        ltm.SubItems.Add("test2")
        ltm.SubItems.Add("test3")
        Me.ListView2.Items.Add(ltm)
        Dim l As New test
        Dim x As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf l.readout)
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class test
    Public Sub readout()
        For Each i As ListViewItem In Form1.ListView2.Items
            Dim command As String = i.SubItems(0).Text
            Dim value As String = i.SubItems(1).Text
            Dim executeon As String = i.SubItems(2).Text
            MsgBox(command & vbCrLf & value & vbCrLf & executeon)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

I heard about invokes and found some sample code. I tried the following as well:

```
 Dim selectedItem = CStr((New Func(Of String)(Function() Form1.ListView2.Items(0).Text)).Invoke)
        MsgBox(selectedItem)
```

However, that did not work either. There are no error messages, it just does not show any messagebox. When I remove the threading and same class, it works just fine. Does anyone know why it does not work?

Comment: Standard VB.NET bug, using Form1 in a worker thread creates a *new* instance of the Form1 class.  You cannot see it unless you add Form1.ShowDialog().  If you fix that bug then you'll get InvalidOperationException.  Don't mess with UI in a worker thread, give it a List(Of String) to work on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you can't touch the UI thread from another thread.   It is hard to tell exactly what you are trying to do, but you could certainly check if you are on a non-UI thread and continue execution on the UI thread using InvokeRequired and BeginInvoke.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim ltm As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem
        ltm.Text = "test1"
        ltm.SubItems.Add("test2")
        ltm.SubItems.Add("test3")
        Me.ListView2.Items.Add(ltm)
        Dim l As New test(ListView2)
        Dim x As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf l.readout)
        x.Start()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class test

    Public Sub New(listview As ListView)
        _listview = listview
    End Sub

    Private _listview As ListView

    Public Sub readout()
        If _listview.InvokeRequired Then
            _listview.BeginInvoke(New Action(AddressOf readout))
        Else
            For Each i As ListViewItem In Form1.ListView2.Items
                Dim command As String = i.SubItems(0).Text
                Dim value As String = i.SubItems(1).Text
                Dim executeon As String = i.SubItems(2).Text
                MsgBox(command & vbCrLf & value & vbCrLf & executeon)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This helped me alot. Thanks for your answer you saved me!

Comment: I'm stuck on another problem now. The code provided was a test project as the actual one is way too big to display. In the test project it works just fine but in the actual one it gives me a nullreference error. Any clue what it could be?